# Запрос на каждую минуту в таблице

Tags: алгоритм, firebird, запрос, sql

Есть таблица, где столбец TS - типа DateTime. И она заполняется каждые 10 секунд примерно. 
Как мне составить запрос что бы данные показывали только за каждую минуту ?

Comment: что значит "только за каждую минуту"?

Comment: Что за SQL у вас?

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть пример данных, и что вы хотите получить.

Comment: я подозреваю, что вопрос в переводе означает: "Как сгруппировать записи по минутам?" , вы это имели в виду?

Answer (score 2):

так?

```
... WHERE TS BETWEEN 
        DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') AND 
        DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00')
```

текущая минута.. можно просто сделать только что прошедшую:

```
... WHERE TS BETWEEN 
        DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') AND 
        DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00')
```

Comment: .

    SELECT 
        *, DATE_FORMAT(`TS`,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') AS `TS_minute`  
    FROM `table`
    GROUP BY `TS_minute`

Comment: В firebird есть [DATEADD()][1]

  [1]: http://firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=dateadd

Answer (score 0):

Есть ли поле дата создания или дата модификации? Можно фильтровать по этим датам.

Comment: Нет таких полей нет.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `TS` > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
```

Comment: Бред. Разве есть команда "INTERVAL 1 MINUTE" ?

Comment: @Пандакун, бред - это то, что вы этого не знаете. Я говорил про MySQL, а если вы используете что-то другое, то не "фыркать" надо, а конкретно указывать в вопросе.

Comment: Есть. А проверить или по гуглить? Там можно как в минутах так и в часах

Comment: Конечно есть 

    SELECT (NOW()+interval 1 minute);
    +---------------------------+
    | (NOW()+interval 1 minute) |
    +---------------------------+
    | 2013-03-05 15:13:10       |
    +---------------------------+

Comment: У вас ведь спросили какую субд вы используете - вы молчите! В MySQL есть такая конструкция. Более того, не проверив, пишите что это бред!

Comment: СУБД у меня MS SQL